# Central angles in circles and measurements and other things I don't understand proving that I shouldn't be doing geometry for math team

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

First off, I'm sorry if this is a simple question and I just don't know geometry.

The question I'm wondering about is from the 2018-19 Meet 4, individual event B for math team:

In $Figure$ $2,$ a circle of radius $20$ contains three points, $A$, $B$, and $C$. Two chords, $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$, are drawn. If the length of $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{BC}$ is $\dfrac{5\pi}{3}$, determine exactly the measure of $\angle{BAC}$.

[image]

The solution that they have stated is $\dfrac{\pi}{24}$. Their explanation is:
"Let x = the central angle intercepting $\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{BC}$. Then $\dfrac{\frac{5\pi}{3}}{40\pi}=\dfrac{x}{2\pi} \rightarrow x=\dfrac{\pi}{12}$. Then $m\angle{BAC}=\frac{\pi}{24}.$" I understand how they solve it once they have $\dfrac{\frac{5\pi}{3}}{40\pi}=\dfrac{x}{2\pi}$, but where do they get those numbers to start with? Is there a specific theorem that I don't have written down on my cheat sheet or it just something simple? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is Euclid Book III Prop 20: https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII20.html

Comment: This is called Inscribed Angle Theorem. Check Ethan Bolker's link.

Comment: @EthanBolker I know that Theorem but where do they get the $40\pi$ and $\dfrac{x}{2\pi}$ from? Is there something specific you need to do when given the arc length to find the angle?

Comment: Recall $c=2\pi r$.